# Squash file with key-value records to CSV

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, perl

I want to write a data parser script. The example data is:

```
name: John Doe
description: AM
email: john@doe.cc
lastLogon: 999999999999999
status: active
name: Jane Doe
description: HR
email: jane@doe.cc
lastLogon: 8888888888
status: active
...
name: Foo Bar
description: XX
email: foo@bar.cc
status: inactive
```

The key-value pairs are always in the same order (`name`, `description`, `email`, `lastLogon`, `status`), but some of the fields may be missing. It is also not guaranteed that the first record is complete.

The expected output is delimiter-separated (e.g. CSV) values:

```
John Doe,AM,john@doe.cc,999999999999999,active
Jane Doe,HR,jane@doe.cc,8888888888,active
...
Foo Bar,XX,foo@bar.cc,n/a,inactive
```

My solution is by using a while `read` loop. The main part of my script:

```bsh
while read line; do
    grep -q '^name:' <<< "$line" && status=''
    case "${line,,}" in
        name*) # capture value ;;
        desc*) # capture value ;;
        email*) # capture value ;;
        last*) # capture value ;;
        status*) # capture value ;;
    esac

    if test -n "$status"; then
        printf '%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n' "${name:-n\a}" ... etc ...
        unset name ... etc ...
    fi
done < input.txt
```

This works. But obviously, very slow. The execution time with 703 lines of data:

```
real    0m37.195s
user    0m2.844s
sys     0m22.984s
```

I'm thinking about the `awk` approach but I'm not experienced enough using it.

Comment: Can any field value have `: ` in them? For example `desc`

Comment: @ibuprofen It should not.

Comment: @ibuprofen Ha, important point. I completely forgot to ask that! Also, can there be empty or comment lines?

Comment: I should say, every line should match any predefined fields. So, comment/empty lines should be ignored.

Comment: Relevant: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following `awk` program should work. Ideally, you would save it to a separate file (e.g. `squash_to_csv.awk`):

```awk
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=": *"
    OFS=","
    recfields=split("name,description,email,lastLogon,status",fields,",")
}

function printrec(record) {
    for (i=1; i<=recfields; i++) {
    if (record[i]=="") record[i]="n/a"
    printf "%s%s",record[i],i==recfields?ORS:OFS;
    record[i]="";
    }
}
    
$1=="name" && (FNR>1) { printrec(current) }

{
    for (i=1; i<=recfields;i++) {
        if (fields[i]==$1) {
            current[i]=$2
            break
        }
    }
}

END {
    printrec(current)
}
```

You can then call this as

```
awk -f squash_to_csv.awk input.dat
John Doe,AM,john@doe.cc,999999999999999,active
Jane Doe,HR,jane@doe.cc,8888888888,active
Foo Bar,XX,foo@bar.cc,n/a,inactive
```

This will perform some initialization in the `BEGIN` block:

- set the input field separator to "a `:` followed by zero or more spaces"
- set the output field separator to `,`
- initialize an array of field names (we take a static approach and hard-code the list)

If the `name` field is encountered, it will check if it is on the first line of the file, and *if not*, print the previously collected data. It will then start collecting the next record in the array `current`, beginning with the `name` field just encountered.

For all other lines (I assume for simplicity that there are no empty or comment lines - but then again, this program should just silently ignore those), the program checks which of the fields is mentioned on the line, and stores the value at the appropriate position in the `current` array used for the current record.

The function `printrec` takes such an array as parameter and performs the actual output. Missing values are substituted with `n/a` (or any other string you may want to use). After printing, the fields are cleared so that the array is ready for the next bunch of data.

At the end, the last record is also printed.

**Note**

1. If the "value" part of the file can also include `:`-space-combinations, you can harden the program by replacing

   ```
   current[i]=$2
   ```

   by

   ```
   sub(/^[^:]*: */,"")
   current[i]=$0
   ```

   which will set the value to "everything after the first `:`-space combination" on the line, by removing (`sub`) everything up to including the first `:`-space-combination on the line.
2. If any of the fields can contain the output separator character (in your example `,`), you will have to take appropriate measures to either escape that character or quote the output, depending on the standard you want to adhere to.
3. As you correctly noted, shell loops are very much discouraged as tools for text processing. If you are interested in reading more, you may want to look at [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Oh wow, this is so fast! `real    0m0.068s` `sys     0m0.016s`

Comment: Yes, `awk` is really efficient for that kind of task ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = ","
    numTags = split("name description email lastLogon status",tags)
}
{
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/ *:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]+: */,"",val)
}
(tag == "name") && (NR>1) { prt() }
{ tag2val[tag] = val }
END { prt() }

function prt(   tagNr,tag,val) {
    for ( tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++ ) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        val = ( tag in tag2val ? tag2val[tag] : "n/a" )
        printf "%s%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    delete tag2val
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
John Doe,AM,john@doe.cc,999999999999999,active
Jane Doe,HR,jane@doe.cc,8888888888,active
Foo Bar,XX,foo@bar.cc,n/a,inactive
```

If you want a header line printed too then just add this to the end of the `BEGIN` section:

```
for ( tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++ ) {
    tag = tags[tagNr]
    printf "%s%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
}
```