# stream one liner every time a specific characters is found from multiple files

Tags: bash, awk

Here is the example of file that I am trying to convert in one line:

```
-
Jun 6th
something2
09:00
some text blah blah
something1
–
Jun 6th
something1
09:00
some text xxx
something1
–
```

I am trying to get these lines as one single line, such as a csv, example:

```
Jun 6th, something2, 09:00, some text blah blah, something1
Jun 6th, something1, 09:00, some text xxx, something1
```

Comment: sorry to mention here, in bash essentially

Comment: Check this out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/655262/squash-file-with-key-value-records-to-csv

Comment: What exactly is the character sequence delimiting the blocks? When I paste your text, the first looks like an ordinary ASCII hyphen, but the other two look like Unicode en-dashes. Are there always 5 lines per block?

Comment: The right solution will depend on the values of `something*` and `some text*`, e.g. whether or not those strings can they contain commas or double quotes or newlines or dashes. So [edit] your question to tell us more about those and provide sample input/output that includes all of the rainy day cases like those.

Comment: Separating your output by `<comma><blank>` instead of just `<comma>` seems like a bad idea as it just makes parsing by subsequent tools more difficult. Do you **really** want to do that?

Comment: Is your input **really** separated by 2 different types of dashes or is one of them a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this SED one-liner:

```
sed -ne '/^–/{g; /./!b; s/\n//; s/\n/, /g; p; z; h; b}; H' INPUTFILE
```

Explanation:

```
/^–/{                 -->  if line starts with char "–", then:
    g                 -->      copy hold space to pattern space
    /./!b             -->      empty line? restart cycle
    s/\n//            -->      get rid of first newline
    s/\n/, /g         -->      replace all other newlines by ", "
    p                 -->      print pattern space
    z                 -->      erase pattern space
    h                 -->      erase hold space
    b                 -->      start new cycle
    }
H                     -->  otherwise, append newline + pattern space to hold space
```

Input:

```
–
Jun 6th
something2
09:00
some text blah blah
some other thing2
–
Jun 7th
something1
10:30
some text xxx
some other thing1
–
Jun 9th
something3
12:15
some text yyy
some other thing3
–
Jun 8th
something4
07:05
some text zzz
some other thing4
–
```

Output:

```
Jun 6th, something2, 09:00, some text blah blah, some other thing2
Jun 7th, something1, 10:30, some text xxx, some other thing1
Jun 9th, something3, 12:15, some text yyy, some other thing3
Jun 8th, something4, 07:05, some text zzz, some other thing4
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it needs to be noted that your data uses two different kinds of dash characters for separation: the ASCII hyphen, as well as the Unicode en dash (U+2013).

The GNU implementation of Awk (GNU Awk) can handle regular expressions for record separation. Here is a one-liner:

```
$ gawk -v RS='\n?[–-]\n' -v FS='\n' -v OFS=', ' '$1 = $1' data
Jun 6th, something2, 09:00, some text blah blah, something1
Jun 6th, something1, 09:00, some text xxx, something1
```

Where `data` is a file containing your example, verbatim.

We set up a record separator regex which matches an optional newline, followed by either an ASCII dash or Unicode en dash, followed by a newline. Then our field separator within these records is the newline. Output separator is a comma and space.

The expression `$1=$1` serves two purposes. Assigning a field back to itself causes the record `$0` to be reconstituted, taking into account the custom `OFS` field separator. So then we just have to print it. Because the data begins with a record separator, there is an initial blank record. For that record, the expression `$1 = $1` assigns the blank value, and since that is the result, the expression is a Boolean false; that record isn't printed.

If we don't include the optional leading `\n` in the `RS` pattern, then each record ends up with an extra blank field, because the newline after `something1` gets interpreted as a field separator. We need the newline which follows the last field to count as part of the record separation. It has to be optional because the file starts with a record separator character not preceded by a newline. Without it we get this:

```
$ gawk -v RS='[–-]\n' -v FS='\n' -v OFS=', ' '$1 = $1' data
Jun 6th, something2, 09:00, some text blah blah, something1,
Jun 6th, something1, 09:00, some text xxx, something1,
```

Extra commas, due to an extra empty field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with tr and sed commands:

```
$ tr '\n' ',' <input_file | sed 's/-,/\n/g' | sed 's/.$//'

Jun 6th,something2,09:00,some text blah blah,something1
Jun 6th,something1,09:00,some text xxx,something1
```

(The second sed gets rid of trailing commas)

You need to make sure the dash-lines separators in your input file are the same. They were not when I copied them to test this code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want valid CSV output, could have quotes or commas in the input, can't have newlines in the `something*`, `some text*`, etc. parts of the records, and only really have `-` as the record separator, here's an input file that would test a potential solution:

```
$ cat file
-
Jun 6th
something2
09:00
"some "text" blah blah"
"something1"
-
Jun 6th
something1
09:00
some, text, xxx
something1
-
```

and here is a solution using any POSIX awk and it's output which is valid CSV:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 == "-" {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        print ""
    }
    sep = ""
    next
}
/[",]/ {
    gsub(/^"|"$/,"")
    gsub(/"/,"\"\"")
    $0 = "\"" $0 "\""
}
{
    printf "%s%s", sep, $0
    sep = ","
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Jun 6th,something2,09:00,"some ""text"" blah blah","something1"
Jun 6th,something1,09:00,"some, text, xxx",something1
```

If that's not the output you'd want given that input then edit the example in your question to show how to handle the cases with `,`s and `"`s in the input.